# Count number of great-grandparent in family relationship using Prolog

Tags: prolog

I have to create a "greatcount" relation in Prolog that counts the degree of great-grandparents between two people. For example, it would return 2 if someone is someone else's great-great-grandparent.

I only have the parent(X,Y) facts where X is Y's parent.

I added the great-grandparent(X,Y) predicate to find out if X is Y's great-grandparent, implemented as follows:

```
great-grandparent(X,Y) :- parent(X,D), parent(D,F), parent(F,Y).
```

I implemented my greatcount predicates like so:

```
greatcount(X,Y,1) :- great-grandparent(X,Y), !.
greatcount(X,Y,N1) :- great-grandparent(X,Z), greatcount(Z,Y,N2), N1 is N2+1.
```

However when the first greatcount relation is not matched, the result is always false (or No). How come?

Comment: Please note that you are defining rules of the form `-(great,grandparent)`, because `(-)/2` is an infix operator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure you have an error? Here's an example that succeeds:

```
parent(pedro, hugo).
parent(hugo, herminia).
parent(herminia, ze).
parent(ze, quim).
parent(quim, tostas).
parent(tostas, faneca).
parent(faneca, xico).

?- greatcount(pedro, faneca, X)
2
true.
```

---

Maybe you're making the mistake in thinking that (using the example I gave),  `tostas` should be the 2nd degree great-grandparent of `pedro`, but that doesn't follow the definition you gave. Be aware, that according to *great-grandparent/2*, the predicate will unify `Z` in your recursive case to `ze`, and then check for the parent of the parent of `ze`; in this case, `faneca`. Otherwise, you'll need to use the following code:

```
greatcount(X,Y,1) :- great-grandparent(X,Y), !.

greatcount(X,Y,N1) :-
  parent(X,D),
  parent(D,F),
  greatcount(F,Y,N2),
  N1 is N2+1.

?- greatcount(pedro, xico, X),
3
true.
```

But this depends on **what exactly constitutes a great-great-grandparent**, and so adjusting the *parent/2* goals in the recursion step of `greatcount` might be required.

Comment: Thanks for enlightening me! I was indeed getting confused with great-grandparent/2. The right result I was looking for was 
`greatcount(X,Y,N1) :-
  parent(X,D),
  greatcount(D,Y,N2),
  N1 is N2+1.`

Comment: @Digitox1n: sure, no problem! It's all a matter of what exactly is a great-great-grandparent :)